# How to catch VueJS errors in NuxtJS SSR (error 500)

Tags: vue.js, error-handling, nuxt.js

I am using NuxtJS SSR with VueJS, if I get an error like this (error 500). Is there a way to log/handle this error globally? In the middleware or something?

[image]

[image]